# how to specify task timeout in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I am wondering if it is possible to do something like -Dmapred.task.timeout= ... when I run pig job? Another way would be to change mapred-site.xml configuration of the underlying hadoop cluster but that's not doable right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my question myself: here is an example: SET mapred.task.timeout 18000

The last number is in milliseconds. (not seconds)

Comment: This doesnt work for me. Still gives me timeout after 300 seconds :/